# Why window.location.href.split("?") array is changing its value itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, browser, location-href

I am trying to reload the page on click of radio buttons (list of cities) by providing the value of radio buttons as query-parameters in URL. Suppose my current URL is

`http://localhost:3001/offers?category=Dining&sub_categories=Home%20Delivery&city=`

And on the selection of any radio button, I want its value to be added to `city` parameter in URL.
So desired URL should be

`http://localhost:3001/offers?category=Dining&sub_categories=Home%20Delivery&city=Mumbai`

But the problem is while modifying the URL, the `sub_categories` are automatically getting stripped off and final URL I am getting is this.

`http://localhost:3001/offers?category=Dining&city=Mumbai`

Here is my code for manipulating URL:

```
$(document).on('click', '.city-selector' ,function(event) {
    event.preventDefault() ;
    var city_name = this.labels[0].textContent.trim().split("(")[0].trim() ;
    var location_string = window.location['href'].split('?');
    if(location_string.length > 1 && location_string[1].indexOf("city") > -1){
      var all_params = location_string[1].split("&") ;
      all_params.splice(all_params.indexOf("city=" + gon.selected_city), 1) ;
      all_params.splice(all_params.indexOf("localities=" + gon.selected_localities), 1) ;
      gon.selected_localities = '' ;
      location_string[1] = all_params.join("&") ;
      location_string[1] = location_string[1] + "&city=" + city_name ;
      window.location.href = location_string[0] + "?" +location_string[1] ;
    }

  }) ;
```

**HINT**: Problem lies in line 
`location_string = window.location['href'].split('?');` When I log the `location_string` array it doesn't contain the `sub_categories` parameter.
Nou sure which thing is stripping it off.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice - negative `start` parameter; there is no `localities=`.

Comment: cant replicate this behavior, is there a fiddle or something?

Comment: @Caramiriel is right pointing out the problem is in splice method. Its first parameter is receiving -1 value and that's why it starts stripping the parameters from back,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use regular expression to replace url:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3001/offers?category=Dining&sub_categories=Home%20Delivery&city=';

var cityName = 'Mumbai';
var cityParams = 'city=' + cityName;


var newUrl = url + '&' + cityParams;
if (url.indexOf('?') === -1) {
    newUrl = url + '?' + cityParams;
} else if (url.indexOf('city=') > -1) {
    newUrl = url.replace(/(city=[\w\d%_]*)/g, cityParams);
}
```

It also working with url like:
http://localhost:3001/offers?category=Dining?city=hanoi&sub_categories=Home%20Delivery

http://localhost:3001/offers

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is:

var url = window.location.href;

var urlParams = url.split('?');

if(urlParams.length > 1) {

urlParams = urlParams[1].split('&');

urlParams.map(function(param){

```
if(param.index('city=')){
    return param += city_name;
}
return param;
```

})

window.location.href = url.split('?')[0] + '?' + urlParams.join('&');

} else {

window.location.href = urlParams[0] + '?' + 'city=' + city_name;

}